# css using grid -template-columns - when the number of columns is unknown

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to dynamically create a div section columns - the number is dependent on the server response.

I want to use the display: grid; and grid-template-columns for displaying this div section as a column.

The problem that I cant set: grid-template-columns, since I don't know the exact number until runt time.

I want all the functionality that the grid css offer,  when the screen size is shrinked the columns down row...

I have the following code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfWidget; i++) {
            let childElement = document.createElement('div');
            parentElement.appendChild(childElement);

            childElement.classList.add('testWidget');
            childElement.innerHTML = 'hello';
```

Comment: What if the server response results in more columns than fit on the screen? Do you want a horizontal scrollbar then? How wide should each column be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat()) function.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
```

Comment: Per the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#funcdef-repeat), using `repeat` with automatic repetitions (`auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) **cannot** be combined with intrinsic or flexible sizes (i.e. `1fr`).